# Jupyter opening up in w3c?

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, w3m

I've installed Jupyter via pip on the windows/ubuntu subsystem. Everything seems to be going well, however, when I try running Jupyter, it opens up the page in the w3m browser. Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhgqW.jpg

When I close the browser, it behaves fine, but it's pretty annoying. How can I get it to not do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html):

You can locate or create a configuration file at `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`. In that file, make sure that the appropriate setting is set to false:

`NotebookApp.open_browser = False`

In my file this setting is included but commented out by default, so you can just uncomment it and change the value if this is the case for you.

Comment: The line wasn't exactly the same, but I just created the config file and found the appropriate line. Thank you!

Comment: `NotebookApp.open_browser = False` didn't work but `c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False` did

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version there is a command line option:

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser
```

Source: https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/running.html#how-do-i-start-the-notebook-server-without-opening-a-browser